# SQL Datatype for LONG text Strings

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

What would be the appropriate datatype for long strings of text. Essentially, 3 normal english paragraphs.

NTEXT gives me 128 limit error
NVARCHAR gives me 128 limit error
TEXT truncates and only picks up the first 1/3

my host is usign an older version of sql, so I do not have nvarchar(max) at my disposal.

SQL

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: TEXT data type should allow for 2,147,483,647 chars, so I am thinking your INSERT/UPDATE logic is truncating, can you post the code for saving the long text to the database?

Comment: I am using the CSV Import Wizard from my host. The tool is called "myLittleadmin"

Comment: Some CSV import tools don't recognize a CR/LF in a text field as text, but rather treat it as a delimiter.   I agree with Karl, more likely to be the tool..

Comment: Occam s Razor. My text field had commas in it.